# socket.io's emit() is not working even though the socket is running in NextJS

Tags: next.js, socket.io

Every time I try to send a message to the socket through my `handleSubmit()` function, it does not trigger the `emit()` function on the API side, and hence the socket isn't able to send the message back to the frontend.

At first I had a 404 server error, but I quickly fixed that up by setting up the socket client side. I used many console logs and the data being sent in is fine, but on the API side only my if `(res.socket.server.io)` is triggering. I followed almost exactly what this guy [had](https://github.com/SarathAdhi/socket.io-starter-template/blob/main/pages/index.js), and he showed a youtube video of it working 10 days ago (so maybe not a version issue). Here is my index.js and socket.js code:

index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

const Home = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socketInitializer();

        return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);

    async function socketInitializer() {
        await fetch("/api/socket");

        socket = io(undefined, {
            path: '/api/socket',
        });

        socket.on("receive-message", (data) => {
            console.log("received data: ", data)
            setAllMessages((pre) => [...pre, data]);
        });
    }

  function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!socket) return;

    console.log("emitted");
    console.log("username: ", username)
    console.log('message: ', message);

    socket.emit("send-message", {
      username,
      message
    });

    setMessage("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chat app</h1>
      <h1>Enter a username</h1>

      <input value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />

      <br />
      <br />

      <div>
      {allMessages.map(({ username, message }, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {username}: {message}
          </div>
        ))}

        <br />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="message"
            placeholder="enter your message"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            autoComplete={"off"}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

socket.js

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {

    if (res.socket.server.io) {
        //this is running
        console.log("Already set up");
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
        path: "/api/socket",
        addTrailingSlash: false
    });
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        // this is not running when calling socket.emit() in client side
        console.log("socket connected.")

        socket.on("send-message", (obj) => {
            console.log("sending from backend")
            socket.emit("recieve-message", obj);
        });
    });

    console.log("Setting up socket");
    res.end();
}
```